# Convolution of $3$ Independent Random Variable for Uniform Distribution

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution

I have a question on convolution of 3 random variables. Below is the given problem:

Let $X_i$ be independent random variables and have a uniform distribution on $(-0.5,0.5)$ for $i = 1, 2, 3$. Find the pdf and cdf of $X_1$ + $X_2$ and $X_1$ + $X_2$ + $X_3$

My solution for $X1 + X2$ is:

- $f_X{_1}+f_X{_2}(z) =
     \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_X{_1}(x)f_X{_2}(z-x)\mathrm{d} x$
- Range of $X_1 + X_2$ is $[-1,1]$

For any $-0.5 < z \leq 0.5$:

$$f_X{_1} + f_X{_2} (z) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_X{_1}(x)f_X{_2}(z-x)dx \\
              = \int_{-0.5}^{z} 1 dx\\
              = z - (-0.5)\\
              =z + 0.5$$

For any $0.5 < z < 1$:

$$f_X{_1} + f_X{_2} (z) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_X{_1}(x)f_X{_2}(z-x)dx \\
              = \int_{z-0.5}^{0.5} 1 dx\\
              = 0.5 - (z-0.5)\\
              =1 - z$$

The conclusion is:

$$f_X{_1} + f_X{_2} (z) = \begin{cases}z+0.5 & -0.5 <z\leq 0.5 \\ 1-z & 0.5 < z < 1 \\ 0 & otherwise \end{cases}$$

My understanding for $X_1 + X_2 + X_3$ are:

- $f_({_X}{_1}_+{_X}{_2}_){_+}{_X}{_3}(z) =
     \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f{_X}{_1}+_X{_2}(t)f_X{_3}(z-t)\mathrm{d} t$
- Range of $X_1 + X_2 + X_3$ is $[-1.5,1.5]$

Then my question for $X_1 + X_2 + X_3$ are:

1. What is the cases for $X_1 + X_2 + X_3$?
2. Can I use the same way of convolution of $2$ random variables
   integration to compute convolution of $3$ random variables?
3. May I know where I can find more information about convolution of
   $3$ independent random variable for uniform distribution?

Comment: There are some serious mistakes already for $X_1 + X_2$. The range should be $[-1,1]$ and the density $f_{X_1 + X_2}$ should be a triangle of base $2$ and height $1$. The range for $X_1 + X_2+X_3$ should be $[-1.5,\,1.5]$. I understand you want to practice the convolution, just note that this is the first two cases (simplest) of the [Irwin-Hall distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irwin%E2%80%93Hall_distribution) shifted to be centered at zero (equivalently, shifted by $0.5$ for every summand (unif r.v.) you have).

Comment: @LeeDavidChungLin thank you very much for your comment and correction

Comment: It's not just a matter of typo. You need to redo the entire calculation.